# 'module' object is not callable - Bio.IUPAC

Tags: python, biopython

When I try,

```
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio import Seq
my_prot = Seq("AGTACACTGGT", IUPAC.protein)
```

Why do I encounter the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

PS: this is an Example from the BioPython's Cookbook

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the BioPython source code the "Seq" class is located in the file "[Seq.py](http://biopython.open-bio.org/SRC/biopython/Bio/Seq.py)" in the path "/Seq/Seq.py"

Meaning... You need to import Seq (a file) which means its a "Module" and then call the class "Seq" within the 'Module' 'Seq'

So try this:

```
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio import Seq
my_prot=Seq.Seq("AGTACACTGGT",IUPAC.protein)
```

If you are ever confused in Python about what you are importing and what you are calling you can do this:

```
import Bio.Seq
print type(Bio.Seq)
>>> <type 'module'>
print type(Bio.Seq.Seq)
>>> <type 'classobj'>
```

Comment: In general, when you see this pattern, the library author may be expecting you to write `from Bio.Seq import Seq`. Then use the `Seq` class as you did in your question.

Comment: Note that since [this commit](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/6d9d97b6c09c9b01d18d81900ae7d33e0d4694ea) that `Seq` has become a new-style class. So now `print type(Bio.Seq.Seq)` will return `<type 'type'>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ben gave a nice clear answer explaining the problem. I guess you copied the example wrong,

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
>>> my_prot = Seq("AGTACACTGGT", IUPAC.protein)
>>> my_prot
Seq('AGTACACTGGT', IUPACProtein())
>>> my_prot.alphabet
IUPACProtein()
```

At least, that's what it currently says http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html

Note that the cause of the confusion would be avoided had Biopython used seq (lower case) for the module, and Seq (title case) for the class - which is now recommended practice for Python, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/